# Styling scrollbar specifically inside a select type input with CSS

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, webkit

Have a site that is styled using JQuery and CSS.  Using a form to gather input for a search and having a problem with the select boxes and scrollbars.

I am primarily developing this for Chrome, and for IE. Right now I am concerned with Chrome, but a cross-platform solution would be nice.

Styling other scrollbars using webkit-scrollbar works just fine:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Styling the select input boxes with the following works just fine as well:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  /*-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
  -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 40%, #E5E5E5);
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  color: #555;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;

}
```

What I cannot seem to bring together is the styling of the specific scrollbar that appears when you click the select input (when enough items are present to cause the scrollbar).

It has no element obviously and I have no idea if it can really be styled or not.  JQuery might be an option, but I don't want to overload the page with plugin after plugin.

Everything else on the page is styled, and the default scrollbars in Chrome and IE really look out of place on the inputs.

I realize creating my own dropdown box and populating a hidden input field could be a way to go, but it seems rather inelegant given how flexible HTML5 and CSS3 is supposed to be, and would be more work and JQuery to add into the page.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The scrollbar of select dropdown can be styled by using this way:

```
select::-webkit-scrollbar
```

In order to let the css take effect, width and height properties need to be set as well. Code below shows the **normal** dropdown, **styled** dropdown but **no width and height properties**, and **styled** dropdown **with width and height properties** to illustrate the difference.

```css
select {
  padding: 3px 12px;
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

select.widthHeight::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

select.style::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  background-color: #ff6536;
}

select.style::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #3677ef;
  border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193);
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Normal</div>
<select>
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 3</option>
  <option>Value 4</option>
  <option>Value 5</option>
  <option>Value 6</option>
  <option>Value 7</option>
  <option>Value 8</option>
  <option>Value 9</option>
  <option>Value 10</option>
  <option>Value 11</option>
  <option>Value 12</option>
  <option>Value 13</option>
  <option>Value 14</option>
  <option>Value 15</option>
  <option>Value 16</option>
  <option>Value 17</option>
  <option>Value 18</option>
  <option>Value 19</option>
  <option>Value 20</option>
  <option>Value 21</option>
  <option>Value 22</option>
  <option>Value 23</option>
  <option>Value 24</option>
  <option>Value 25</option>
</select>

<div>Styled without width and height css</div>
<select class="style">
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 3</option>
  <option>Value 4</option>
  <option>Value 5</option>
  <option>Value 6</option>
  <option>Value 7</option>
  <option>Value 8</option>
  <option>Value 9</option>
  <option>Value 10</option>
  <option>Value 11</option>
  <option>Value 12</option>
  <option>Value 13</option>
  <option>Value 14</option>
  <option>Value 15</option>
  <option>Value 16</option>
  <option>Value 17</option>
  <option>Value 18</option>
  <option>Value 19</option>
  <option>Value 20</option>
  <option>Value 21</option>
  <option>Value 22</option>
  <option>Value 23</option>
  <option>Value 24</option>
  <option>Value 25</option>
</select>

<div>Styled</div>
<select class="style widthHeight">
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 3</option>
  <option>Value 4</option>
  <option>Value 5</option>
  <option>Value 6</option>
  <option>Value 7</option>
  <option>Value 8</option>
  <option>Value 9</option>
  <option>Value 10</option>
  <option>Value 11</option>
  <option>Value 12</option>
  <option>Value 13</option>
  <option>Value 14</option>
  <option>Value 15</option>
  <option>Value 16</option>
  <option>Value 17</option>
  <option>Value 18</option>
  <option>Value 19</option>
  <option>Value 20</option>
  <option>Value 21</option>
  <option>Value 22</option>
  <option>Value 23</option>
  <option>Value 24</option>
  <option>Value 25</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot style the select element, or at least not very well. It would be nice to have the option to, but there are so many values I would want to alter that its just easier to create my own. Just basically make a div with clickable elements that change the value of a hidden input and that can be shown and hidden with a separate element which shows the selected value.

Personally I feel this is the best way as you have FULL control over it allowing it to be styled how you want, however, you can also use javascript UI plugins like jQuery UI that change the styles of input elements.

Comment: The select element can be styled.  The code I pasted works quite well.   What is missing is the ability to style the dropdown that is created when it is clicked.  That has no elements and is not part of the DOM.  The scrollbars are not part of the DOM either, but they can be styled too with CSS.  What is frustrating is that Chrome is not styling the *specific* scrollbar inside the dropdown box.  So my real question is does there exist any specific CSS that will style it for Chrome?

Comment: There is no way to style the drop down menu of a select box or the arrow, only the appearance of the text input area. As I said, the best way to do this would be to create a custom script that replaces the select element with a textbox and a hidden div that contains divs to replace the options.

Comment: It really depends on the size of the project as to whether this would be worth doing. Generally a user will only see the dropdown for a few seconds. There is also the fact that is used to seeing the default dropdown and a custom one could be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A related thought to whether to use JS and an alternate HTML markup to achieve the desired aesthetics. Would "hacking" it for the sake of aesthetics cause unwanted results on mobile browsers? On an iPad, the default functionality for a select element is to bring up a wheel of options to select. Would we not then lose that functionality by hacking the select?

Answer (score -5):

You can style the dropdown, etc.  I've done it many times.  As far as the scrollbar, do it the same way you do anything else.